# Can an android phone be tracked on find my phone app etc if the sim has been removed and had an factory reset?

Tags: applications

Can an android phone be tracked last location on find my phone app etc if the sim has been removed and had an factory reset?

Answer (score 2):

[Google help](https://myaccount.google.com/find-your-phone) says

> To find, lock, or erase an Android phone, that phone must:
>
> Be turned on
>
> Be signed in to a Google Account
>
> Be connected to mobile data or Wi-Fi
>
> Be visible on Google Play
>
> Have Location turned on
>
> Have Find My Device turned on

After a factory reset, your account is removed from the phone and without SIM it's not connected to internet.

So **no**, it can't

Comment: is this true for FRP where google account remains bonded after reset?

Comment: My understanding is that **all** conditions need to be met. After a factory reset, wifi credentials are wiped, you can't enter the device to activate wifi, no SIM, so I think the logic holds that find my device won't work. But yes to be sure one needs to test @alecxs

Comment: @alecxs Í assume you mean factory reset protection. After resetting the device, you are not really logged in the Google accout, probably just the connection between phone ID and device ID is remembered somewhere (on the phone or at Google). Maybe Google could implement Find my phone even for your case, but this assumes that the thief in quite inexperienced, so the impact is questionable. Also, it could bring some negative PR like “Google tracks you even after factory reset”, regardless of good intentions.