# Finding the location of a lost android device

Tags: huawei

I've lost a huawei p30 device.let's say somebody took it and formatted it and started using it with other accounts.

Is there any way to track it and find its location?

i have tried the find my phone of google and although it seemed to be somewhere nearby suddenly i lost it and the battery seemed to be around 50%

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can an android phone be tracked on find my phone app etc if the sim has been removed and had an factory reset?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219645/can-an-android-phone-be-tracked-on-find-my-phone-app-etc-if-the-sim-has-been-rem)

Comment: The question may not match yours but the answer would tell you why you can't locate your phone anymore